# editor.widgets.add not found in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('simplebox', {

    requires: 'simplebox',

    icons: 'alarm',

    init: function (editor) {
        editor.widgets.add('simplebox', '');
    }
});
```

Here is my problem; the firefox couldnot find any `editor.widgets.add` in `.js` file. What should i do now? I am using CKEditor.

Answer (score 0):

Your plugin should require [`'widget'`](http://ckeditor.com/addon/widget) plugin, not `'simplebox'`. And of course you have to have this plugin available in your build (if you use one).